# How to set up nodejs + nginx on windows 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, nginx-location

I am using nodejs + nginx on windows 8 following [This tutorial](https://websanova.com/blog/nginx/installing-node-js-with-nginx-proxy) and set up using [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) i am getting "**Hello World**" at port " http://127.0.0.1:3000/" and at port "3000" but at "http://robstodo.com/" its not working as i write command for start nginx server :- **start nginx** only black screen is blinking , How i can know my app is running on nginx server ? and in which file should i change. Its my **server.js**

```js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

It's my **nginx.conf**

```js
http {
  //server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  //...
  upstream app_robstodo {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.robstodo.com robstodo.com;
    access_log /path/to/logs/nginx/minitorials.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_robstodo/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me i got stucked at this point.

Comment: Did you point dommain `www.robstodo.com` into your windows 8? Use `hosts` file in windows 8 to add your domain to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan where i will point domain in windows 8? And here will use hosts file in windows ?

Answer (score 1):

For temporary test with your domain, you should use `hosts` file in windows 8.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

In hosts file add:

```
127.0.0.1 robstodo.com
```

Then save, and access http://robstodo.com/ again.

For point your domain to web-server (in this case, windows 8 is webserver)

1. You should [create A record](https://www.google.com.vn/search?espv=2&q=create%20a%20record&oq=create%20a%20record&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.26864.30043.0.30286.15.13.0.2.2.0.187.1258.2j9.11.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.13.1267...0i67j0i131j0i3.YZOjS4Sj_mE) in domain control panel.
2. Configure [Port forwarding](https://www.google.com.vn/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=port%20forwarding&oq=port%20forwarding&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j0l4.4719j0j4) on your router which beside the webserver

Comment: I mad the changes as i run command "nginx -s reload"  getting - "nginx :[emerg] no "events" section in configuration "  error from nginx cmd.

Comment: follow it https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#