# Node.js + Nginx Setup: Could not access domain name

Tags: node.js, nginx

Hi I am encountering the issue same with [How to set up nodejs + nginx on windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141805/how-to-set-up-nodejs-nginx-on-windows-8). I tried the solution given in this link by adding it in the host file but it is still not working. Can you give me other solution to this problem? Thanks.

When I am accessing robstodo.com in the browser, I have this [robstodo.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBvWx.png)

```html
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
 
 upstream app_robstodo {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
 }

 server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name robstodo.com;
  access_log \logs\minitorials.log;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://app_robstodo/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Post the nginx donfig you have used? Also is `robstodo.com` to a registered domain? Have you made a host entry if this is not using DNS?

Comment: I added the nginx config above. 
" Also is robstodo.com to a registered domain?"
I am not sure if I get this, but I only added this domain name in the host entry in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host Then add 127.0.0.1 robstodo.com

Answer (score 0):

If that is not a registered domain and you're using a hosts file, then in addition to this:

```
127.0.0.1 robstodo.com
```

also add this:

```
127.0.0.1 www.robstodo.com
```

because that's what you are using in your screenshot, a `www` subdomain.

You need to use exactly the same domain in your hosts file, in the nginx config and in your browser. The www.robstodo.com is a completely different domain than robstodo.com as far as the name resolver is concerned. Also note that you need to have the `app_robstodo` domain defined as well.

Now, I would try to hunt the problems with little steps. Can you access the Node app directly using IP address with no proxy? Can you access it using the app_robstodo domain name with no proxy? Can you access the nginx proxy with the IP address? And finally can you access the nginx proxy with the domain name?

Make sure that you use the correct **ports** on each step.

Comment: 1.)  Thanks for the clarification. :) By the way, 
I added 
    127.0.0.1            robstodo.com
    127.0.0.1            www.robstodo.com
in hosts file, then run nginx -s reload, but error is still the same.
2.) What do you mean by also defined the app_robstodo?  I already declared it in the nginx conf as
    upstream app_robstodo {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

Comment: 3.) Node app directly using IP address with no proxy? I can access it in browser via 127.0.0.1:8080 or 127.0.0.1:3000 
4.) Can you access it using the app_robstodo domain name with no proxy?  Can you access the nginx proxy with the IP address? Can you access the nginx proxy with the domain name? -- I am new to this, can you give me an exmaple how to perform this. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i think it is okay now. I directly input the http:127.0.0.1:3000 to proxy pass instead of using upstream. thanks for your help.